# How to add a field to all documents where first 100 docs having a value of 1 next 100 having a value of 2 and so on?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with 10,000 documents. I want to add a new field to each document that contains a string value where the first 100 documents should have a value of "1", the next 100 documents should have a value of "2", and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One options is to use `$setWindowFields`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {date: 1},
      output: {value: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {
      value: {$toString: {
          $add: [
            {$floor: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$value", 1]}, 100]}},
            1
          ]
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nOc6x6etVzA)

Comment: But I don't have any date in my documents. What's the use of that?

Comment: You need to sort by something, you can replace this with any other field you wan to sort by

Comment: If you want to persist this new field permanently in the documents, you need to add a `$merge` stage as well.